# PHP error: Undefined index: submit

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP: “Notice: Undefined variable”  and “Notice: Undefined index”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

In this once the submit button is clicked it retrieve the data from database. But once i enter this page  **Undefined index: submit** is shown before i click the submit button.

```
<div id="title">
    <form method="get" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>">
        <h3>Select your product and click submit</h3><br />
        <select name="prod">
            <option value="default">Select your product</option>
            <option value="os">Operating Systems</option>
            <option value="mobile">Smart Mobiles</option>
            <option value="mobile">Computers</option>
            <option value="shirt">Shirts</option>
        </select><br /><br />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit"/>
    </form>
```

The php code is:

```
<?php
    $submitcheck=$_GET['submit'];
    echo $submitcheck;
    if (!isset($submitcheck)) {
        echo 'Pls select and submit';
    } else {
        ....
    }
```

?>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to change your PHP to:

```
if (isset($_GET['submit']))
{
    // Form has been submitted
}
else
{
    // Form has not been submitted
}
```

At the moment, you're assigning a value which might not exist to `$submitcheck` and then checking whether it's set. You need to do it the other way round: check `$_GET['submit']` is set, then assign it to a variable.

Comment: thnq Jamie.. Helped for my stupid quest

Answer (score 1):

It's bacause you code is executed from top to bottom and on the top you are using `$_GET['submit']` and then this key does not exist. You could do something like that:

```
if(array_key_exists('submit', $_GET)){
   echo $_GET['submit'];
}
```

or even

```
if (!isset($_GET['submit']))
{
    echo 'Pls select and submit';
}
else
{
 ....
}
```