# How to fix Notice: Undefined index in PDO

Tags: php, mysql

i have

Notice:  Undefined index: _ava in C:\xampp\htdocs\otakutangerang_admin\edit_user.phpon line 26

```
 $avatar = $_POST['_ava'];
```

Notice:  Undefined index: _skill in C:\xampp\htdocs\otakutangerang_admin\edit_user.php on line 27

```
$usr_skill = $_POST['_skill'];
```

and this my code

```
  if (isset($_POST['update'])) {

  $id = $_GET['id'];
  $email = $_POST['_em'];
  $fname = $_POST['_fn'];
  $lname = $_POST['_ln'];
  $web_usr = $_POST['_web'];
  $usr_note = $_POST['_note'];
  $avatar = $_POST['_ava'];
  $usr_skill = $_POST['_skill'];

  //Retrieve the user account information by id.
    if ($object->Update($id, $email, $fname, $lname, $web_usr, $usr_note, $avatar, $usr_skill)) {
      $msg = "<div class='alert alert-info'><strong>WOW!</strong> Record was updated successfully <a href='index.php'>HOME</a>!</div>";
    } else {
      $msg = "<div class='alert alert-warning'><strong>SORRY!</strong> ERROR while updating record !</div>";
    }
  }

  if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    extract($object->Details($id));
  }
```

This my form to change and edit the database

```
    <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST">
      <div class="box-body">
        <div class="form-group">
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
          <label for="inputUserName" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Username</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputUserName" value="<?php echo $username; ?>" disabled>
            <p class="help-block"><em>You require permission from Administrators to change it.</em></p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="inputFirstName" class="col-sm-2 control-label">First Name</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" name="_fn" class="form-control" id="inputFirstName" value="<?php echo $fname; ?>">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="inputLastName" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Last Name</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" name="_ln" class="form-control" id="inputLastName" value="<?php echo $lname; ?>">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="inputEmail" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="email" name="_em" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" value="<?php echo $email; ?>">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="inputEmail" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Website</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" name="_web" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" value="<?php echo $web_usr; ?>">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="inputEducation" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Education</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="email" name="_edu" class="form-control" id="inputEducation" placeholder="Education">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="inputNote" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Notes</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <textarea class="form-control" id="inputNote" value="<?php echo $usr_note; ?>" placeholder="Note" name="_note"></textarea>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="inputSkill" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Skill</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <select class="form-control select2" name="_skill" value="<?php echo $usr_skill; ?>" multiple="multiple" data-placeholder="Skill" >
              <option value="Rasengan">Rasengan</option>
              <option value="Chidori">Chidori</option>
              <option value="Susano'o">Susano'o</option>
              <option value="Kamehameha">Kamehameha</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="inputRole" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Role</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputRole" value="<?php echo $id_admrole; ?>" disabled>
            <p class="help-block"><em>You require permission from Administrators to change it.</em></p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="inputFile3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Foto Profil</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <div class="input-group">
              <label class="input-group-btn">
                <span class="btn btn-primary">
                  Browse&nbsp; <input type="file" style="display: none;" accept="image/*" multiple id="file">
                </span>
              </label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="_ava" value="<?php echo $avatar; ?>" readonly disabled>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
            <button type="submit" name="update" class="btn btn-danger" value="update">UPDATE</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- /.box-body -->
    </form>
```

Comment: This has been asked and answered many times like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undef), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842759/php-undefined-index), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14415341/php-error-undefined-index-submit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `isset()`

```
$avatar = isset($_POST['_ava']) ? $_POST['_ava'] : null;

$usr_skill = isset($_POST['_skill']) ? $_POST['_skill'] : null;
```

and same other `post value` . hope it will help you

for more information

http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

Comment: is it not working?

Answer (score 0):

These notices you receive when error_reporting is set also to display E_NOTICE.
However, this is a best practise I think (first check whethere $_POST exists and whether array key exists too):

```
$avatar = isset($_POST) && array_key_exists('_ava', $_POST) ? $_POST['_ava'] : "";
$usr_skill = isset($_POST) && array_key_exists('_skill', $_POST) ? $_POST['_skill'] : "";
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the two rows to this:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['_ava']))
    $avatar = $_POST['_ava'];
else
    $avatar = null; //or any other default value

if(isset($_POST['_skill']))
    $usr_skill = $_POST['_skill'];
else
    $usr_skill = null; //or any other default value
```

The notice comes up because the _skill or _ava isn't set.

Answer (score 0):

You should only use the attribute readonly, not disabled. [Check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22989845/how-do-i-post-disabled-input/22990008#22990008)

- readonly: input can't be modified
- disabled: input has no form function

And also check form input is isset, like below:

```
$avatar = null;
if(isset($_POST['_ava'])) {
   $avatar = $_POST['_ava'];
}
```